# AMDeviceValidatePairing failed

Tags: mobile, frameworks, itunes

While using Fruitstrap (or some other tools which uses MobileDevice.h) for installation of apps, we come across this error:
AMDeviceValidatePairing failed

How to solve this in MAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are using fruitstrap, it actually uses [MobileDevice.h](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/MobileDevice_Library) for accessing the MobileDevice.framework. MobileDevice.framework is actually contacting iTunes and doing the required process. In between it opens up a process and fails to terminate:
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/Resources/**usbmuxd** -launchd

On terminating this process, it will solve the problem and AMDeviceValidatePairing will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error in fruitstrap.

My problem was that iTunes was not authorized to access data from my mobile(since I had just update to 7.1.1).

So I opened iTunes once, gave authorize in the dialog which opened. In the device a popup asked me if I wanted to "Trust this computer". Once I gave yes, I got this error no more.